# How to use pydantic models in subclass with graphene-pydantic and graphene in python?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, pydantic

### Use Case Scenario

I've two pydantic models. Each in his own module (file). One Model, the *TUser* depends on the *TAddress*.

address_model.py

```py
class TAddress(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int]
    address: Optional[constr(max_length=100, strip_whitespace=True)]
    city: Optional[constr(max_length=80, strip_whitespace=True)]
    postal_code: Optional[constr(max_length=15, strip_whitespace=True)]
    country: Optional[constr(max_length=3)]
```

user_model.py

```py
class TUser(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = None
    email: Optional[EmailStr]

    address: Optional[TAddress]

    is_active: Optional[bool]
    is_email_verified: Optional[bool]
    created_at: Optional[datetime.datetime]
```

If I use the *TUser* model know for my PydanticObjectType

```py
class UserType(PydanticObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TUser
```

I get the following error message:

```
graphene_pydantic.converters.ConversionError: Don't know how to convert the Pydantic field ModelField(name='address', type=Optional[TAddress], required=False, default=None) (<class 'app.address.serializers.TAddress'>)
```

It seems like that there is a problem when using pydantic models from different modules that depends on each other.
What is the solution for this use case?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The error message gives you the hint you need.

```
Don't know how to convert the Pydantic field ModelField(name='address'....
```

What's happening is that Graphene doesn't know how to convert the address class to be able to use it with the `TUser` because it is part of the `PydanticObject`.

In order to get rid of your error, you need to define a `PydanticObjectType` referring to `TAddress`, this way Graphene will know what is the relationship between these two objects.

In your schema file where you have the `UserType` just do this:

```py
class AddressType(PydanticObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TAddress

class UserType(PydanticObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TUser
```